# Mongodb docker container exit instantly after starting

Tags: mongodb, docker

Hello im trying to create a docker container for Mongodb

Install worked well and everything looked fine at `docker ps --all`

But when i started the Docker and then did `docker ps --all` again it shows up like `Exited (14) 3 seconds ago`... So for me it looks like that it instantly after starting the docker exited it, and cause of that i cant run any commands like `docker exec -it (ID) bash` because i get a deamon Error that the container is not running.

What can i do about that? Google solutions didnt helped until now...

**Infos**

```
   - Ubuntu Version: 20.04 Focal
   - Image: mongo:4.4-focal and mongo
   - Docker Version: 20.10.7
```

**Commands Used**

Installed with: `docker run mongo:4.4-focal`

1. Command im running: `docker start (ID)`
2. Docker answers with printing ID (like it should when the Container is online)
3. Command im running: `docker exec -it (ID) bash`
4. Error: Error response from daemon: Container (A longer ID) is not running

Comment: A good first step would be to start the container in the foreground (without a `docker run -d` or `docker-compose up -d` option) and see what it prints out in its logs.  Editing this question to include a [mcve] would also be helpful – what's the exact command you're running, what other application source code is important, what is that log output?

Comment: @DavidMaze i eddited it a bit, and for now no other source code is importent... Im atm just testing Dockers to maybe migrate a project into them. And the log output are about 200-300 lines and i tbh dont know that of that is important and what not...

Comment: The last 50 lines or so should include some indication of why the container stops